# How to open youtube videos in WebView?

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I have this kinds of link
http://www.youtube.com/v/NbvsiNnTlCg?autohide=1&version=3&autoplay=1

and i want to open it in webview.

But when i send this url it opens a blank page.

I tried using this code

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled (true); 
myWebView. getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically (false);
myWebView. getSettings().setPluginsEnabled (true);
myWebView. getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows (false);
myWebView. getSettings().setSupportZoom (false);
myWebView. setVerticalScrollBarEnabled (false);
myWebView. setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled (false);
myWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

in webview class

Comment: Webview has lots of problems loading video..try Youtube Api for Android..It's Simple and Easy.

Comment: can you tell any link for that?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can try adding following lines into your code

```
    myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 8);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    // these settings speed up page load into the webview
    myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```